# Upon Vs. On in the sentence?

Tags: difference, prepositions

While conversing with my friend I got confused between these two sentences:

> It depends upon the context.
>
> It depends on context.

Which one is more apt in usage and why?

Comment: Sud, I would use "on", not "upon", because my book says that "depend" preferably takes "on" and because "upon" is justifiable when something occurs. However, according to other theories, you should use "from", not "on" nor "upon". But I cannot post an answer because I'm sure natives can say a lot of things on this matter :)

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I don't think we'd say, "It depends _from_ context." _From_ has a lot of meanings and usages, but that's not one of them.

Comment: @J.R. Well, icicles *depend from* eaves . . .

Answer (score 5):

*On* is a preposition **unbounded by time**. *upon* is a preposition that is **bounded by time**:

1. *On* arrival at the station he should buy a sandwich - NB there is no time/date specified.
2. *Upon* arrival he bought a sandwich - NB it is still a preposition, but we know the event has occurred, and hence that it was bounded by time.

There is a clear difference.

Answer (score 4):

On and upon can be used interchangeably here.  Both of the following sentences are correct:

> It depends on context.
>
> It depends upon context.

Both of these sentences mean that, in general, whatever "it" refers to will change based on whatever context it is in.

You add *the* when you're being more specific about what that context is:

> It depends on the context of the situation.
>
> It depends upon the context of the situation.

In this case we have specified *which* context (the context *of the situation*) so it requires the article.

In practice, all four sentences mean the same thing.  Personally I'd be more likely to use the general "It depends on context" and the specific "It depends upon the context [insert description here]", but that's just personal use.  Any of the above are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

Both are valid, however as can be seen by the following Ngram, **depends on context** is much more commonly used in modern English than **depends upon context**, since about 1960:

[image: Google ngram for depends on context versus depends upon context]

Comment: where can I generate these graphs?

Comment: @BlackJack21 it's called 'google ngram viewer'

Answer (score 0):

*On* is more formal than *upon*, and the British National Corpus and the Corpus of Contemporary American English show it is more frequently used than *upon* in both British and American English. However, the difference in frequency is much greater in American English than in British English.

Answer (score 0):

where there is no action, we use "on" where there is an action we use upon for example
The duster is on the table
Bring the duster and keep it upon the table.