# 'on vs upon' and 'in vs into'

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> 'on vs upon' and 'in vs into'

They are very similiar and I think there could be an equation, literllay: upon= up+on and in+to.

Is ther any big difference when learners of English should keep in mind?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upon Vs. On in the sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4675/upon-vs-on-in-the-sentence) That's one of your ***two*** questions here - the other should be covered by [Usage of into vs in vs inside.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18366/usage-of-into-vs-in-vs-inside)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most uses, *on* and *upon* are interchangeable: except in some set expressions, *on* is more common. There are some transferred meanings of *on* where you can't use *upon* (for example, *on television*, *on Thursday*) but others where you can (eg as a temporal conjunction *on seeing him* = *upon seeing him*).

*Into* always has a meaning of movement or transition. *In* can have this meaning (eg *I put it in/into the car*), but is also used for static position (*It was in the car*) and in this sense, it cannot be replaced by *into*.